Are all NoSQL databases semi-structured?
From Semi-structured data - Wikipedia:

Semi-structured data is a form of structured data that does not obey the tabular structure of data models associated with relational databases or other forms of data tables, but nonetheless contains tags or other markers to separate semantic elements and enforce hierarchies of records and fields within the data. Therefore, it is also known as self-describing structure.

From NoSQL - Wikipedia:

NoSQL (originally referring to "non-SQL" or "non-relational") is an approach to database design that focuses on providing a mechanism for storage and retrieval of data that is modeled in means other than the tabular relations used in relational databases.


Are tabular/relational database and structured database the same?
Are NoSQL database and semi-structured database the same?
If both are yeses, then why do we categorize databases as structured and semi-structured, but not tabularly structured and non-tabularly structured? I think that NoSQL databases are very structured.


Are tabular/relational database and structured database the same?
No. SGML, XML, and MARC (used in library catalogue systems) are all structured data, but they are not naturally tabular/relational. Storing and querying them in a SQL database would require extensions.
It's a similar story for databases that can be stored in a tabular form, but isn't naturally queried that way, such as graph-structured data.
Are NoSQL database and semi-structured database the same?
No, and the obvious counter-example is that the term "NoSQL" can also apply to databases for unstructured data, such as free-form text.

Do you mean that all non-unstructured data, can be stored in SQL with some extensions? Wikipedia lists XML as semi-structured data. Do you think it's correct?

I'm honestly not sure about this terminology, and I used to get paid to write database servers. However, the Wikipedia article opens with "Semi-structured data is a form of structured data [...]" and I guess that makes sense?

so I take that non-unstructured data and structured data are the same (or unstructured data is the complement of structured data). NoSQL data is the union of non-tabularly structured data and unstructured data. Not using the term "semi-structured data" would make everything clearer. Am I correct?

In my headcanon, "NoSQL" is any database model for which SQL is a poor fit. After reading that paper on semi-structured data, the argument seems to be that "semi-structured data" is any scenario where the structure is part of the data, as would be the case with something like JSON or XML.

As the Wikipedia article for Semi-structured data opens with "Semi-structured data is a form of structured data [...]", I take that non-unstructured data and structured data are the same (or unstructured data is the complement of structured data). NoSQL data is the union of non-tabularly structured data and unstructured data. Not using the term "semi-structured data" would make everything clearer.
